# Is $R$ a ring or an unit ring in a random literature?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Some books claim that a ring is not necessarily a unit ring. This is the original definition and containing a monoid is not necessary for a ring.

Others assume that $1 \in R$

Both of them often claim that they use the most accepted definition.

When encountered a random literature which do not bother to give definition of a ring, shall I assume that $1 \in R$ or not?

Are there some politics going on here, just like the dissent from Dirac $\delta$ "function"?

Comment: I think people in most fields of mathematics think of a unital ring when talking about rings.

Comment: Thanks. Then 2n is not a ring :[

Comment: No politics. People care about different properties. Geometers and number theorists mostly fancy commutative, unital rings. Representation theorists and general algebraists also often work with non-commutative unital rings and I think people working in functional analysis may quite frequently encounter non-unital rings as well (not sure though).

Comment: Non unital rings do appear in interesting contexts (functional analysis, for instance), but the main problem with them is doing sensible module theory, which is what algebraists are mainly concerned with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the most likely assumption you can make, but there is likely to be exceptions (other than it might denote the set of real numbers).

What you should do in such a scenario, where it's not explicitely mention is to observe how it's used. If you for example see that the book refers to the multiplicative identity without the explicit mention of it being present then the book would probably mean that the existence of it is implicit. The converse is if the book explicitely requires the existence of a identity in some of the theorems (then you assume that it isn't implied otherwise).